# What is an intrinsic value type?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What is an intrinsic value type, and what is the difference to non-intrinsic value types?

I couldn't find documentation about the effect of the option "Function returning intrinsic value type without return value." in Visual Studio's VB.Net project properties' Compile page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there doesn't seem to be any documentation here.

Consider this code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() is {0}", Foo())

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

    Function Foo() As Integer

    End Function

End Module
```

With the default project properties, which have "Function returning intrinsic value type without return value" set to Warning, this compiles with this warning:

> warning BC42353: Function 'Foo' doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a 'Return' statement?

and outputs

> Foo is 0

By setting That project property to Error, we can make this warning halt compilation with an error.

The 'intrinsic' part comes into play if we change the code to this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() is {0}", Foo())

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

    Function Foo() As Bar

    End Function

End Module

Structure Bar
    Public a As Integer
End Structure
```

Now, even though `Bar` is a value type, the code compiles with no warning whatever that project property is set to. We can therefore conclude that `Integer` is an 'intrinsic' value type, but our `Bar` is not.

What none of this tells us is what counts as an 'intrinsic' value type. Googling around, I found [this page](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/datatypes.htm) which tells me that if I fire up the Object Browser, right click in the left-hand pane and tell it to Group By Object Type, I see this:

[image]

which I think is the best we're going to get.

Comment: Then "Object" is a intrinsic reference type (whatever that means), and the others are the intrinsic value types?

Comment: @Tiago Yes; I would guess from this evidence that 'intrinsic' just means 'defined in mscorlib' ...

Comment: @AakashM: `System.Guid` is a value type defined in mscorlib, but it's not an intrinsic type (i.e., no missing return value warning).

Comment: @Heinzi I meant 'defined *as intrinsic* in mscorlib'. It is now a little late after the grace period for editing comments :)

Comment: @AakashM: It appears to be exactly those types for which a [specific Visual Basic type name exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/). Thus, I assume that it is not hard-coded in mscorlib (which is language agnostic) but rather in the compiler.

Comment: @Heinzi with the arrival of Roslyn on github, I suppose it is possible to get a definitive answer now. Maybe I will have time to look into it...

Answer (score 2):

"intrinsic" can be taken as "built-in" in this case.

And it seems not all that relevant, you are simply missing a return.

Comment: That option didn't flag anything when compiling the project when set to warning/error. But I could not find any documentation and I'm a supercurious type.