# Why does VB.NET's "missing return value" warning specifically exclude "non-intrinsic value types"?

Tags: vb.net, language-lawyer, roslyn

Consider the following code example:

```
Function f1() As Object     ' yields warning BC42353
End Function

Function f2() As Int32      ' yields warning BC42353
End Function

Function f3() As DateTime   ' yields warning BC42353
End Function

Function f4() As Guid       ' no warning
End Function
```

and the following project settings:

[image: project settings]

Apparently, VB.NET makes a difference between the following three categories of types:

1. reference types [Example f1],
2. "intrinsic" value types (some apparently undocumented subcategory of value type, see [What is an intrinsic value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5003715/87698)) [Examples f2 and f3],
3. "non-intrinsic" value types [Example f4],

and offers "missing return value" warnings for 1 + 2, but not for 3 (no such compiler option available).

**What is so special about "non-intrinsic value types" that the language designers decided to omit this feature for this category of types?**

(I suspect that this was a deliberate decision, since (I assume) it would have been easier to implement the feature for all value types than to check for some hard-coded "intrinsic" white-list first.)

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2337835/87698 is related but not a duplicate. It's a question from the old days when VB.NET supported warnings for reference types only.

Comment: Put that Int32 in a Structure and return that structure instead and there's no warning, so weird.

Comment: It's amusing you've tagged it `language-lawyer`, because from a spec perspective, this is an easy one: the specification doesn't document any of this, the end. In fact, it's even worse than not documenting intrinsic types, warnings and all of that: it doesn't actually document what happens if a function with a return type returns nothing (no, not `Nothing`). All it documents is what happens if you use `Exit Function` without assigning or returning. It's easy to infer the same happens with an empty function, but the whole point of a specification is so you don't have to infer things like this.

Comment: The intrinsic value types are the ones that existed in previous versions of VB and for which VB.NET has a keyword in the language.  The only non-obvious one is Date, an alias for DateTime.  I *think* the warning was added to help programmers deal with legacy code.  Not declaring the function return type or forgetting to assign the return value on all code paths was very, very common.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Good point. Do you have a better idea for a tag that conveys *"I don't need help using the language, I have a question about the compiler itself"*?

Comment: @HansPassant: As far as I remember, `UShort`, `UInteger` and `ULong` did not exist in previous versions of VB (nor do they exist in VBA). But I agree that it matches exactly those types for which a VB.NET keyword exists.

Comment: @Heinzi: no -- but you could just put that explanatory sentence in the question, no tag needed.  I just wanted to rag on the VB.net spec for a bit, and complain that there's no fun in being a language lawyer if the "law" itself is vague.

Comment: "Intrinsic" means "belonging to a thing by its very nature" or the like. "Intrinsic" value types are those types that are part of the VB language itself. Extrinsic value types would be any that VB can use but are not part of the language.  Why MS decided to distinguish between them in this case, I'm not too sure but I would not be surprised if it was related to upgrading VB6 code.

Comment: True, unsigned types were not part of VB6 but they were not part of VB.NET originally either.  The `UInt16` structure and the like were only added to .NET in version 1.1 and the `UShort` and similar keywords weren't added to VB until 2005 or 2008 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Given the source code of Roslyn VB compiler flow analysis source code and especially in the data flow pass that can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/fab7134296816fc80019c60b0f5bef7400cf23ea/src/Compilers/VisualBasic/Portable/Analysis/FlowAnalysis/DataFlowPass.vb#L1250-L1301) in line 1232 starts the sub that decides if this warning should be generated. Please note that I assume that based on various  searches I performed in the repository.

The if statement starts in line 1250 which is as follows:

```
                If type.IsIntrinsicValueType Then


                    Select Case MethodSymbol.MethodKind
                        Case MethodKind.Conversion, MethodKind.UserDefinedOperator
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValOpVal1
                        Case MethodKind.PropertyGet
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValPropVal1
                        Case Else
                            Debug.Assert(MethodSymbol.MethodKind = MethodKind.Ordinary OrElse MethodSymbol.MethodKind = MethodKind.LambdaMethod)
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValFuncVal1
                    End Select


                ElseIf type.IsReferenceType Then


                    Select Case MethodSymbol.MethodKind
                        Case MethodKind.Conversion, MethodKind.UserDefinedOperator
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValOpRef1
                        Case MethodKind.PropertyGet
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValPropRef1
                        Case Else
                            Debug.Assert(MethodSymbol.MethodKind = MethodKind.Ordinary OrElse MethodSymbol.MethodKind = MethodKind.LambdaMethod)
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValFuncRef1
                    End Select


                ElseIf type.TypeKind = TypeKind.TypeParameter Then
                    ' IsReferenceType was false, so this type parameter was not known to be a reference type.
                    ' Following past practice, no warning is given in this case.


                Else
                    Debug.Assert(type.IsValueType)
                    Select Case MethodSymbol.MethodKind
                        Case MethodKind.Conversion, MethodKind.UserDefinedOperator
                            ' no warning is given in this case.
                        Case MethodKind.PropertyGet
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValPropRef1
                        Case MethodKind.EventAdd
                            ' In Dev11, there wasn't time to change the syntax of AddHandler to allow the user
                            ' to specify a return type (necessarily, EventRegistrationToken) for WinRT events.
                            ' DevDiv #376690 reflects the fact that this leads to an incredibly confusing user
                            ' experience if nothing is return: no diagnostics are reported, but RemoveHandler
                            ' statements will silently fail.  To prompt the user, (1) warn if there is no
                            ' explicit return, and (2) modify the error message to say "AddHandler As 
                            ' EventRegistrationToken" to hint at the nature of the problem.
                            ' Update: Dev11 just mangles an existing error message, but we'll introduce a new, 
                            ' clearer, one.


                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValWinRtEventVal1
                            localName = MethodSymbol.AssociatedSymbol.Name
                        Case Else
                            warning = ERRID.WRN_DefAsgNoRetValFuncRef1
                    End Select
                End If
```

As you can see the only condition that a warning is not generated is if the type TypeKind property equals to TypeParameter. I really don't know more about those kind of types but I assume that there are some classes / types in the .NET framework (GUID must be one of them) that behave this way.

It doesn't seem to be a decision at all rather than a designed behavior of the compiler in certain types. However I can see from the code that it isn't so hard to add that warning based on the type of the method (function in this case) regardless the returning type which in my opinion is the best thing to do.

Hope this helps.